# R: remove duplicate by name columns while keeping the max value per every position

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a big table 5000 by 2000 with the values provided below.
I need to get rid of columns with identical names while keeping the maximum for every position in a column (for all duplicates).

I am stuck.. I have a similar code for removing duplicates by rownames

```
x <- setDT(x)[, lapply(.SD, max), cName]
```

but I don't know how to do the same trick but by column

```
prot1   prot1   prot1   prot2   prot3
0.889618286 0.907433399 0.085730039 0.010259207 0.01203583
0.766053072 0.061778787 0.193634896 0.387856898 0.029151237
0.399227213 0.980691544 0.30179994  0.768697098 0.749744349
0.089657475 0.353170832 0.85146464  0.580683125 0.606756472
0.341599883 0.790159839 0.653031942 0.011711575 0.569486433
0.627587607 0.363081942 0.628312001 0.137380824 0.535160381
```

so the cleaned version is

```
prot1   prot2   prot3
0.907433399 0.010259207 0.01203583
0.766053072 0.387856898 0.029151237
0.980691544 0.768697098 0.749744349
0.85146464  0.580683125 0.606756472
0.790159839 0.011711575 0.569486433
0.628312001 0.137380824 0.535160381
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`, we could create a new dataset ('x1') with the unique columns of 'x'.  Split the sequence of 'prot' columns by the column names, use that index to subset 'x', get the `max` value per row with `pmax`, and assign the output in the list to the 'prot' columns of 'x1'.

```
 x1 <- x[unique(colnames(x))]
 x1[-1] <- lapply(split(2:ncol(x), colnames(x)[-1]),
     function(i) do.call(pmax, x[i]))
 x1
 #   cName    prot1      prot2      prot3
 #1    c1 0.9074334 0.01025921 0.01203583
 #2    c2 0.7660531 0.38785690 0.02915124
 #3    c3 0.9806915 0.76869710 0.74974435
 #4    c4 0.8514646 0.58068312 0.60675647
 #5    c5 0.7901598 0.01171158 0.56948643
 #6    c6 0.6283120 0.13738082 0.53516038
```

Or using `data.table`, we can get the index of unique column names in a vector ('nm1'), create a 'data.table' with number of columns equal to the length of 'nm1' and number of rows same as the original dataset ('dt1').  Convert `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT`).  Using a `for` loop, we can `set` the values in each column of 'dt1' as the maximum value of the row for each unique column names in 'x' (`do.call(pmax,`).

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- unique(colnames(x)[-1])
dt1 <- as.data.table(matrix(NA, ncol=length(nm1), nrow=nrow(x), 
                dimnames=list(NULL, nm1)))
setDT(x)

for(j in seq_along(dt1)){
 set(dt1, i=NULL, j=j, value= do.call(pmax,x[,colnames(x) %chin% 
                           nm1[j], with=FALSE]))
 }

 dt1
 #      prot1      prot2      prot3
 #1: 0.9074334 0.01025921 0.01203583
 #2: 0.7660531 0.38785690 0.02915124
 #3: 0.9806915 0.76869710 0.74974435
 #4: 0.8514646 0.58068312 0.60675647
 #5: 0.7901598 0.01171158 0.56948643
 #6: 0.6283120 0.13738082 0.53516038
```

#### Benchmarks

On a bigger dataset

```
 set.seed(24)
 x1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5000*2000), ncol=5000))
 set.seed(42)
 colnames(x1) <- sample(paste0('prot', 1:100), 5000, replace=TRUE)

 library(gtools)
 nm2 <- mixedsort(unique(colnames(x1)))
 dt2 <- as.data.table(matrix(NA, ncol= length(nm2),
          nrow=nrow(x1), dimnames=list(NULL, nm2)))
 setDT(x1)
 system.time({
    for(j in seq_along(dt1)){
       set(dt2, i=NULL, j=j, value= do.call(pmax,x1[,colnames(x1) %chin% 
                           nm2[j], with=FALSE]))
   }
})

# user  system elapsed 
#  0.019   0.000   0.019
```

#### data

```
x <- structure(list(cName = c("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6"), 
prot1 = c(0.889618286, 0.766053072, 0.399227213, 0.089657475, 
0.341599883, 0.627587607), prot1 = c(0.907433399, 0.061778787, 
0.980691544, 0.353170832, 0.790159839, 0.363081942), prot1 =
c(0.085730039, 
0.193634896, 0.30179994, 0.85146464, 0.653031942, 0.628312001
), prot2 = c(0.010259207, 0.387856898, 0.768697098, 0.580683125, 
0.011711575, 0.137380824), prot3 = c(0.01203583, 0.029151237, 
0.749744349, 0.606756472, 0.569486433, 0.535160381)), 
.Names =   c("cName", 
"prot1", "prot1", "prot1", "prot2", "prot3"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: it's very-very slow... (

Comment: @JohnAmraph  One option would be to split only the columns that have duplicate ids and use the `lapply` route.

Comment: @JohnAmraph I updated with an option using `data.table`. Check if that is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Akrun's answer:
The first solution works fine for a small dataset, but assumes your variables are in ascending/alphabetical order. If your variables are not ordered, you can use the following (using x from Akrun's post):

```
x1 <- data.frame(sapply(split(1:ncol(x), colnames(x)), function(i) do.call(pmax, x[i])))
```